# How can I view Paragon Tier feats in the Character Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, dnd-4e-character-builder, paragon-tier

I'm DMing a 4E campaign for my friends who have never played any D&D game before. So far they're loving it. We're using the old character builder that WOTC released a while back, that you run from your own PC.

Only problem is that they're fast approaching Paragon Tier, and the character builder doesn't appear to show Paragon or Epic Tier feats.

I've got DDI subscription, and had a look over the Compendium, which DOES have the information there, but it's slow, and there's over 600 feats to look over, which is going to make it hard for my players to see their options - they're the kind to absolutely inspect everything. The character builder helps with this, as you can just scroll through and read the description on the right. We need to be able to see those feats in the character builder, somehow.

How can I view the Paragon Tier feats in Character Builder?

Comment: I'm editing this to be a complete question and answer on the character builder, rather than one about a compilation of feats.

Comment: Also, please be sure to use the online character builder now that you have DDI, versus the offline one. Its not a rules resource like the compendium (every once in awhile it has a weird glitch), but its way more up to date with errata and published materials.

Answer (score 5):

Paragon Tier feats *are* in the character builder, but only show up under the right circumstance: You need to be level 11, AND have the level 11 feat slot selected in order to have them show up.

Keep in mind however that this is not a good way to select feats, as only the feats you *currently* qualify for are shown. If a feat that would be absolutely positively great for you, but requires for example a martial multiclass before, will be hidden from you for ever. Primal Eye comes to mind for RBA types. I suggest reading the class guides on community.wizards.com

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as accepted when you can! :)

Comment: If I recall, there's a checkbox somewhere that allows you to see feats you do not qualify for. I know this option *definitely* exists in the online character builder.

Comment: You can click on the little orange house at the top of the screen, then you can select any feat you *know* the name or description of. Even if there were a checkbox to list all feats, there are 3266 of them at the moment. Just read the guides and some builds.